# Why I cant JSON.parse a string from an API (Error msg: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>))

Tags: javascript, json, api, parsing

I am trying to fetch a joke using XMLHTTPRequest from a random joke generating API as practice.

Here is my code

```
    <script>
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('get', 'https://icanhazdadjoke.com/', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json')
        const joke = JSON.parse(xhr.response)

    xhr.onload = function () {console.log(xhr.responseText)}
    xhr.send();

</script>
```

and the error message i get is:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse ()

Funny thing is if I do JSON.parse(xhr.response) and save it to a variable, it works perfectly fine. What am I doing wrong in my script?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to parse the response *before receiving* the response.  (AJAX is asynchronous.)  You need to handle the response in the `onload` handler, just like you already are when you try to log it to the console:

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('get', 'https://icanhazdadjoke.com/', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

xhr.onload = function () {
  const joke = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
  console.log(joke);
}
xhr.send();
```

Comment: thank you!, i am a little bit more familiar with xmlhttprequest() now